# Web service client class works; but deployment error when used in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic, webservice-client, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 12c to generate a 'Web Client and Proxy' from a WSDL file. It worked fine and generated a Client class to test out the invocation of the service. This client works fine.

I then generated a test servlet and ensured it worked.

I pasted the same web service invocation code into a servlet, and at deploy time I am getting this exception:

```
    Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.parseAnnotations(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:199)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.parseAnnotations(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:150)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.createTargetRef(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:106)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.ServiceRefProcessorImpl.bindServiceRef(ServiceRefProcessorImpl.java:385)
at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceRef(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1109)
at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1073)
at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindServiceReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1418)
at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindEnvEntriesFromDDs(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1986)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.activate(CompEnv.java:198)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.activate(WebAppServletContext.java:2797)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1648)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:804)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:317)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:313)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:121)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

I'm not getting a lot of useful results on Google. Can you please help ? thanks !

Comment: This is almost always because of a class loading problem. Your probably have more than one jar file with the same class in it that causes `WLSProvider` to fail. Check for ear/war for jars already on the weblogic classpath

Comment: You are 100% correct. I pruned my project's lib folder and found that jaxb-api and jaxb-impl were the culprits. I removed them and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Same exception here and solved by removing the jaxb-impl dependency (by setting de maven dependency scope to provided)

Answer (score 0):

Placing the metro-default.xml in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF resolves the issue. As Tube based messaging is introduced , jaxws-ri-2.2.8 jars are required to make the web services work.